# Why won't my program import pynput in terminal but does so in PyCharm?

Tags: python

I installed pynput with pip and imported it into my code. However, when I run my code in the terminal, it won't run and gives me this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\toofast4u\projects\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'
```

I have looked through all available modules I can use in python, and I can't seem to find pynput.

I tried reinstalling it to see if that would work, but the same problem persists. Can anyone find the issue?